# My ubuntu system won't start after upgrade....any help on removing or re-installing with USB?

Tags: upgrade

I have just previously upgraded my Ubuntu from 14.04TLS to 14.10....
everything was looking good during the installation [mainly] but than after the downloading and then booting i get this:

Starting version 219

(Would post an image but i cant due to *not enough rep.*

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to "rescue a broken system".

Assuming the disk is good, this would be a good time to backup things before the problem gets worse. Generally people run a live or memory resident distro for this.

Things will be a little different depending upon UEFI bios being in use.
If you have UEFI bios, you will have a half gig FAT partition. You can see these with parted or even gparted from a live distro.

In any case, using a distro usb or cd, get into "rescue a broken system".
You want to use the rescue disk's kernel and "pivot root" to run your broken system. Generally you can identify the "root" partition, on simple systems it is the largest. You would mount the EFI partition as /boot/efi.

A few assumptions have been made. Re-install grub, the below assumes 64 bit and efi.

grub-install --bootloader-id ubuntu --target=x86_64-efi /dev/sdb

Apologies if you are past GRUB. There are many similar questions, even on other sites that can give you step by step instruction

https://superuser.com/q/376470

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I'm new to all this, Do you think maybe i should just wipe and reinstall? I have all my files already on the cloud

Comment: Yes indeed, where this becomes painful is having to re-install packages and applications and any config that goes along with that, but most have to do it sooner or later. If you use another disk you may be able to pick and choose from what is not on the cloud. Not everything will be under /home. So, don't wipe - start with a fresh disk, or the very least copy the partition or files somewhere.